# How to manage two shipping methods at once?

Tags: shipping-methods

I have a scenario, where I want to enable two shipping methods at once, and make theme dependent on the type of product in the cart. If products with attribute A are in the cart, then shipping price with shipping method X, should be shown. If product with attribute B are in the cart, then price with shipping method Y should be shown. 
And if both are in the cart then prices for both needs to be calculated and displayed, individual to products corresponding to each attribute/shipping method?
Any ideas how can this be managed in magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento No allow to enable two shipping method at once for different type of product according to attribute set.
You need to add a different extension or OPC step to make this functionality workable.